Периодические ошибки о невозможном подключении к серверу телеграмма. Aiogram
Есть телеграмм бот который работает уже 3 месяца, где то недели 2 назад начались периодические ошибки о невозможном подключение к серверу телеграмма, хотя интернет там есть.Есть идеи как можно это исправить?
python --version

Python 3.11.5

python -m pip show aiogram

Name: aiogram
Version: 3.3.0
Summary: Modern and fully asynchronous framework for Telegram Bot API
Home-page:
Author:
Author-email: Alex Root Junior <jroot.junior@gmail.com>
License:
Location: C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
Requires: aiofiles, aiohttp, certifi, magic-filter, pydantic, typing-extensions
Required-by:

python -m pip show aiohttp

Name: aiohttp
Version: 3.9.1
Summary: Async http client/server framework (asyncio)
Home-page: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp
Author:
Author-email:
License: Apache 2
Location: C:\Users\adelt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
Requires: aiosignal, attrs, frozenlist, multidict, yarl
Required-by: aiogram

Бот запушен на пк на windows 11,время на пк правильное.Пример ошибок:
Failed to fetch updates - TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [getaddrinfo failed]
Sleep for 1.000000 seconds and try again... (tryings = 0, bot id = *******))
Failed to fetch updates - TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [getaddrinfo failed]
Sleep for 1.264188 seconds and try again... (tryings = 1, bot id = *******))
Failed to fetch updates - TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [getaddrinfo failed]
Sleep for 1.678613 seconds and try again... (tryings = 2, bot id = *******))
Failed to fetch updates - TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [getaddrinfo failed]
Sleep for 2.187897 seconds and try again... (tryings = 3, bot id = *******)


Проблема была в операторе связи, который не справлялся со своими обязанностями. Из-за этого интернет стал очень медленным и выдавал ошибку.
